# Is there a way to distirbute hybrid app other than playstore?

Tags: cordova

I developed a cordova based hybrid app. But now i have to intgerare this hybrid app with a web app. Is this possible? The hybrid app i developed is a part of the webapp. reason is anyone who is using the web app on any mobile be able to use my hybrid app. Also I dont want the users to download my app from playstore or any url. Is there a way?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Considering that all mobile devices have browsers that likely support the webapp already, what's the problem?

Comment: I am not worried about the web app. As you said webapp is accesible everywhere. My problem is how do i integrate my hybrid app with the already developed web app?

Comment: Considering we have no idea what either one of them does, or what sort of communication you're talking about, it's rather difficult to provide any help.

Comment: ok. sorry for being vague. lets say the web app has a button and on clicking the button the hybrid app should start working independent of the mobile device without downloading the app exclusively. Let me know if you need anything in specific. Thanks

Comment: At least can we distribute a hybrid app other than app store. if so, how?

Comment: You don't have to have it on the store.  You can just put it on a web page.  However...  Most people don't like (or allow) installing from unkown sources.  There is a security setting, by default, that prevents it.

Comment: thanks. So, now could you please provide me the way to bundle the two together. I am not sure of bundling them without losing hybrid nature.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself time and distribute it via the play store - for free if you like.

Registering for the Google play store is almost free (compared to apples fees) and does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is kinda a requirement not to go through the playstore. That is my major concern.

Comment: You really should have a word about that requirement.  Like I mentioned above, almost ALL devices dissallow downloading apps from unkown sources.  So no one will be able to use your app.

Comment: yeah. The reason behind the requirement is this app is not for everybody. It is secure with login and only for organisation purpose. so probably not more that 1000 will use this app. But as you said i will have a word about downloading apps from unknown sources. My other question is " Is there a way that we can embed hybrid app so they dont have to download?" The hybrid app is a scanner. so user should open the scanner as soon as he clicks button in the web app. Thanks

Comment: Add a login screen to the app. Mention in the description that it is only for registered users of x.

Comment: It is possible to get a company license from apple ($299) when you can setup a mini itunes store privately. Windows  store also offers this functionality. I'm not sure about android though.